# Export two library which have same class name

Tags: dart

I met an error when exporting two libraries. And these libraries have exactly same class name.

File: `A.dart`

```dart
library chrome.A;
class MyClass {
...
}
```

File: `B.dart`

```dart
library chrome.B;
class MyClass {
..
}
```

File: `C.dart`

```dart
library chrome_app;
export 'A.dart';
export 'B.dart';  // HERE!! error message for the element 'MyClass' which is defined in the libraries 'A.dart' and 'B.dart'
```

Is this the intended result?

I think `A.dart` and `B.dart` has their own namespace so that there should be no error.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

A library name isn't a namespace. Dart doesn't have namespaces.
What you can do in Dart is to specify a prefix for an import.

You have to import those libraries separately if you want to use them in the same library instead of just one import with `import 'C.dart;'`

```dart
import 'A.dart' as a;
import 'B.dart' as b;

var m = a.MyClass();
var n = b.MyClass();
```

If you just want to avoid the conflict and don't need both classes exported you can.

```dart
library chrome_app;

export 'A.dart';
export 'B.dart' hide MyClass;
// or
export 'B.dart' show MyOtherClass, AnotherOne; // define explicitly which classes to export and omit MyClass
```

Comment: Note that hide/show can also be used on the import statement. Does not solve OP's question, but solved my related question.